# ruby assigning value to array using enumerable method

Tags: arrays, ruby

I was just digging ruby and want to know why I am not able to re-assign a value to an array element using enumerable method (`first` or `last`).

I know I can assign values with index but I want to know more about this. I didn't find much explanation in [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/first) and [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-first).

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array1.first # returns 1
array1.first = 7
NoMethodError: undefined method `first=' for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:Array

Ruby 2.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Because there is [`Array#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), but there is no `Array#first=`. Are you asking why they didn't put one?

Comment: As several readers have said, there is an instance method [Array#[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) but no instance method `Array#first=`. It's as simple as that. Is `Array#first=` needed? No, because one can use `[]=`. Is `Array#first` (which we have) needed? No, because one can use [Array#[\]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) (which, incidentally, is as different from `Array[]=` as night is from day). So why do we have `Array#first` but not `Array#first=`? Because those who argued for the addition of the latter carried the day.

Comment: @h.APP.y "assign with index" is not what it looks like - not assignment, but method invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways this question can be read:

1. Technically, why does the indexing solution work, but not the `first` one?

The reason is that in order to be able to use `foo.bar = :baz`, `foo`'s class has to implement the `bar=` method.

```
class X
  def initialize(y)
    @y = y
  end

  def y
    @y
  end
end

x = X.new(3)
x.y     # => 3
x.y = 7 # => NoMethodError: undefined method `y=' for #<X:0x007fb272726d80 @y=3>

class X
  def initialize(y)
    @y = y
  end

  def y
    @y
  end

  def y=(new_y)
    @y = new_y
  end
end

x = X.new(3)
x.y     # => 3
x.y = 7
x.y     # => 7
```

The core library does implement [`Array#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), but does not `Array#first=`.

2. What is the reason they decided not to implement `Array#first=`?

The `first` method is actually part of [`Enumberable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) and if one class implemented `first=`, it would look inconsistent if there was no implementation of `Enumerable#first=`.

And this can't happen because for some enumerables such method doesn't make sense ([`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html)). It will also require more of you to get the enumerable functionality. As of right now, for a class to become enumerable, it just needs to implement an `each` method and include the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) module.

Comment: I don't understand your point #2. Which method does "The method is..." refer to? Why would it be inconsistent to have `Array#first=` but not `Enumerable#first=`, considering that we  have `Array#[]=` but not `Enumerable#[]=`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, the `Array#[]=` is not inconsistent, because there is no `Enumerable#[]`. Therefore, indexing is an extension in `Array` which does not originate from `Enumerable` and there is no expectation other enumerables to also be indexable. That is what I meant. *The method is...* was referring to `Enumerable#first`.

Answer (score 1):

The array method `.first` is a attribute reader method, it does not have writing permission. Check out the [Ruby Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) for array . You need to reassign a value at a specific index in the array just follow what @Andrey wrote

Comment: I didn't find anywhere in the document #first " does not have writing permission" . Have you. Sorry if I missed in the doc. This is what I got from doc `Returns the first element, or the first n elements, of the array. If the array is empty, the first form returns nil, and the second form returns an empty array. See also #last for the opposite effect.`

Comment: @h.APP.y: that's what the doc says: "returns element". Nowhere does it say "Oh and by the way, you can also **set** elements with this"

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create `first(12)` , imagine how awkward the method first would be if you can set `first=(12,arr)` , the method become ambiguous (if the array doesn't have 12 elements, should it add the elements or should it edit the x first elements) because `first(12)` of an array of 5 elements returns the 5 elements. writing such a method like that will violate the single responsibility principle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `x.first(12) = foo` is invalid syntax :)

Comment: "will violate the single responsibility principle" - many methods in ruby violate SRP. So it's not like _this reason_ ever stopped anyone. :)